# How to return the variable "a" in the function below

Tags: java, android

It's a simplified function.

It keeps returning `0` while I expect this to return 5. How come?

```
public int accessKey() {

    a = 0;

    mSubscription = mAccountManager.getLoginPassword()
            .flatMap(loginPassword -> mServerAPI
    .getProfilesList((new BaseRequest(
            loginPassword.getLogin(),
            loginPassword.getPassword(),
            ClientGetter.getClientFromManager(),
            CodeSnippets.getSha256(ClientGetter.getClientFromManager()))
            )))
            .doOnNext(profilesListe -> mProfilesList = profilesListe.getItems())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<BaseResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    a =5;

                   }
                      
    return a; }
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value) will help you understand why it returns as 0. while your code isn't really in the same format as the examples, it's still asynchronous and not synchronous

Comment: does my answer help you out ? do you have any further questions ?

Answer (score 0):

**It's because of the asynchronous or non blocking behaviour** , Normally during the scenarios of API calls fetching some data from database ,these behaviours we handle asynchronously,because otherwise your application will get stuck This post will help you to solve this matter.  [Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value)

Answer (score 0):

you're executing an asynchronous operation here. your code doesn't execute "top down" here but will be executed on a different thread - Rxjava shifts this entire operation over to another thread and then returns the result to the thread specified, but this doesn't happen immediately. by the time your subscribe code has executed (we don't know when that will be) your return statement has already executed.

you could try change your code to something like this (just as an idea, i don't have any code similar to yours to create a working example):

```
 return mAccountManager.getLoginPassword()
        .flatMap(loginPassword -> mServerAPI
.getProfilesList((new BaseRequest(
        loginPassword.getLogin(),
        loginPassword.getPassword(),
        ClientGetter.getClientFromManager(),
        CodeSnippets.getSha256(ClientGetter.getClientFromManager()))
        )))
        .doOnNext(profilesListe -> mProfilesList = profilesListe.getItems())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

this means that your method will now return an observable, which you can then subscribe on and subscribe to those changes where they are used.

this means that the signature of your method will have to change to support this new return type and the calling method will have to subscribe to this observable.

---

you describe your question as a simplified function, but I'll give you an even simpler (complete) example:

```
public Observable<Integer> foo() {

    return Observable.just(5);

}

public void usage(){

  Disposable disposable = foo().subscribeOn(something).observeOn(something).subscribe(
   //inside this subscribe, like you'd normally do, you'd find the result of 5
  )
 ...
 //handle disposable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the Callback interface method and it worked! Many thanks